# how to make a back up of the whole android studio 3.0.1?

Tags: android

How to make a full backup of Android studio 3.0.1?

I want to format my PC but I don't want to download Android studio again and its data should not be lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio itself is less than a few hundred MB.

The Android SDK, emulators, and Maven cache take more space, and you can back  them up separately.

Maven is in a hidden `.m2` folder in your user profile directory

Android SDK might be within the Android Studio folder, or another hidden folder `.android`. You can find that from the SDK Manager. I think the emulators are there too

You'll have to re-download Android Studio, but there's a separate installer that doesn't include the SDK

Your code should be backed up to source control

Comment: Thx, for help ,

Answer (score 0):

You can **Export settings** in **File** menu and import when reinstall everywhere.